# Constructing database for simulation performance data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, csv, database-design

Currently, my team has a script that clones the latest version of our code every night and runs a set of long-running cases on our computing cluster. Each case outputs a `performance.csv` in its' respective directory. This has resulted in a monolithic directory structure filled with git repos for each night going back about 2 years.

I would like to store this performance data in a database so we can understand how our code has changed in performance over-time.

I don't know anything about databases and I'm not sure what's the best way to craft the tables.

I've written a python script that fetches all of the performance data for each git-repo and stuffs it into a sqlite database with no index or key.

Here is a simplified example of my filesystem

```
- projects/git/
  - git_20200501/
      |---- assessment/test01/performance.csv
      |---- assessment/test02/performance.csv
      |---- assessment/test03/performance.csv
  - git_20200502/
      |--- assessment/test01/performance.csv
      |--- assessment/test02/performance.csv
      |--- assessment/test03/performance.csv
  - git_20200503
      |--- assessment/test01/performance.csv
      |--- assessment/test02/performance.csv
      |--- assessment/test03/performance.csv
```

I've used pandas to read in the data and added a few columns to help make each record unique. The resultant dfs look something like this

```
repo_root                   repo_hash  repo_date path                              simulation_alive_time
/projects/git/git_20200501  8cdf06...  20200501  assessment/test01/perfomance.csv   0.000000
/projects/git/git_20200501  8cdf06...  20200501  assessment/test01/perfomance.csv   0.438507
/projects/git/git_20200501  8cdf06...  20200501  assessment/test01/perfomance.csv   0.614212
/projects/git/git_20200501  8cdf06...  20200501  assessment/test01/perfomance.csv   0.710791
/projects/git/git_20200501  8cdf06...  20200501  assessment/test01/perfomance.csv   0.808077
```

I then just do a nested for-loop; looping through all the repos and its subsequent performance csvs and append it to the database.

Am I going about this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 is perfect for this project and doesn't require that much knowledge to get it up and running.

```
from sqlite3 import connect
connection = connect('database/YourDatabaseName.db')
```

connect will create a database for you. it is also how you access in to your database after it is alreaddy created

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

from here your sql will differ depending on what you are trying to do. There is a plethora of sql copy and paste data out there, but a few of the main methods are create table and add values. Data in these databases are stored in tables so to enter data you will have to make a table in your database.

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE TableName (DataFeature1 DataType1, DataFeature2 DataType2);"
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
```

commit saves your changes to your db. SQL has it's own specific data types depending on your use case you will have to look up the exact kind but like I said before really easy stuff to find and copy / paste

One big tip I will give you is never put records in one at a time you can do up 1,000 at once I believe, but the format is a little different.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `TableName` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (Entry1Col1, Entry1Col2),(Entry2Col1,Entry2Col2), ...;"
```

you would then execute this sql to upload all of your entries and their corresponding columns. Hope this helps!